# Which word is more appropriate to be used “along” or “together”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to ask a supplier to:

> 1. Please put inside the color packing box the manual **along** with the product.
> 2. Please put inside the color packing box the manual **together** with the product.

Are these words interchangeable in this context and either one of them can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little change will make the question more clear. It's the confusion between the phrases *along with* and *together with*. *With* is added there because when you add it, they become idioms.

> [together with (idiom)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/together_1#together_1__49) - including; **in addition to**; as well as

And,

> [along with something (idiom)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/along_2#along_2__26) -**in addition to** something; in the same way as something

Clearly, if you mean *in addition to*, both are interchangeable in that context. If I were a supplier, either is okay to understand that you need both - manual and product.

However, over both those sentences, I'd prefer telling this - *Please put manual (inside the color packing box) as well.*

That's because we are likely to suggest putting *manual* (as they are likely to forget it!) but it is very unlikely that if don't instruct anything, only manual comes and not the product!